# How to write an update query in MySQL with AES_ENCRYPT?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is my code that I wrote when user wants to change his password.

```
s2.executeUpdate("UPDATE user SET AES_ENCRYPT(password='"+newpw1+"','key') WHERE uid='"+pubvar.uid+"')");
```

But it doesn't work, can someone correct it for me and post it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you mean,

```
UPDATE user 
SET password = AES_ENCRYPT('" + newpw1 + "','key') 
WHERE uid = '" + pubvar.uid + "')
```

better use `PreparedStatement` to prevent from `SQL Injection`.

```
String _upd = "UPDATE user SET password = AES_ENCRYPT(?,'key') WHERE uid = ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(_upd);
pstmt.setString(1, newpw1);
pstmt.setString(2, pubvar.uid);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)