# how to update aes encrypt with Java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have been searching for examples where update query is performed in Advanced Encryption Standard  with java, but couldn't find any except for [update query in MySQL with AES_ENCRYPT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795736/how-to-write-an-update-query-in-mysql-with-aes-encrypt).

The code below functions, but the data is not encrypted, my question is how can I update the data with AES_ENCRYPT

```
    try{
    String value1 =  jTextFieldID.getText();
    String value2 = jTextFieldFirstname.getText();
    String value3 = jTextFieldMiddlename.getText();
    String value4 = jTextFieldLastname.getText();
    String value5 = ((JTextField)txt_Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String value6= Gander.toString();
    String value7= jTextFieldAddress.getText();
    String value8 = jTextFieldCity.getText();
    String value9 = jTextFieldPostcode.getText();    
    String sql = "update  Customer set ID='"
            +value1+"',FirstName='"
            +value2+"',MiddleName='"
            +value3+"',LastName='"
            +value4+"',DOB='"
            +value5+"',Gander='"
            +value6+"',Address='"
            +value7+"',City='"
            +value8+"',PostCode='"
            +value9+"'where ID='"
            +value1+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is updated");

}
catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

The AES_DECRYPT

> SELECT ID, AES_DECRYPT( FirstName,  'uk112' ) AS FirstName,
>   AES_DECRYPT( MiddleName,  'uk112' ) AS MiddleName, AES_DECRYPT(
>   LastName,  'uk112' ) AS LastName, AES_DECRYPT( DOB,  'uk112' ) AS DOB,
>   AES_DECRYPT( Gander,  'uk112' ) AS Gander, AES_DECRYPT( Address, 
>   'uk112' ) AS Address, AES_DECRYPT( City,  'uk112' ) AS City,
>   AES_DECRYPT( PostCode, 'uk112' ) AS PostCode
>       FROM Customer

Comment: which column you want to encrypt? or all columns?

Comment: yes all except for ID and DOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have you tried this?

```
String sql = "update  Customer set FirstName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),MiddleName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),LastName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),DOB=?,Gander= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),Address= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),City= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),PostCode= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112') where ID=?";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, value2);
    pst.setString(2, value3);
    pst.setString(3, value4);
    pst.setString(4, value5);
    pst.setString(5, value6);
    pst.setString(6, value7);
    pst.setString(7, value8);
    pst.setString(8, value9);
    pst.setString(9, value1);
    pst.execute();
```